# Did 13.04 fix the resetting shortcut bug?

Tags: shortcut-keys, 13.04, bug-reporting

I have experienced this problem in both 12.04 and 12.10.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/964270 (12.04)
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1063617 (12.10 and later)

I'm wondering if someone could confirm that this bug is fixed in 13.04.
If it's not, I probably won't upgrade. That's my only annoyance with 12.10 now.

Thanks.

Comment: I answered, but this question isn't very constructive, since if you actually READ the bugs you'd see which bug is targeted against what, and you'd also see that the 12.10 and later one was already fixed.  This also doesn't really fit with our Q&A guidelines.

Comment: My bad, sorry. That's the first time I look at a bug report and I just ignored the "status". Sorry again.

Comment: No problem, things happen.  As a bugcontrol member, I habitually check the status of a bug and look for certain keywords in the bug description to answer these types of questions, so... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would read the description on each bug, you'd know that [1063617](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1063617) was for 12.10 and later.  That is "Fix Released", so it should be fixed already in Raring.